# Extra Health from Death Rage in Gauru form?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, werewolf-the-forsaken

> If a werewolf ever suffers a wound that exceeds his
>   Health dots (it would cause him to go unconscious or start
>   bleeding to death), and the attack could trigger Death
>   Rage (say, it’s an exceptional success that inflicts five or
>   more points of damage), the roll to resist Kuruth is made
>   before the character is decreed unconscious or down. The
>   timing of events here is important, because a character
>   entering Death Rage gets four extra Health dots by virtue
>   of assuming Gauru form. Those extra Health might allow
>   him to remain conscious where he would have collapsed
>   in another form. If the Resolve + Composure roll fails,
>   the character enters Death Rage and assumes Gauru,
>   potentially gaining more Health dots if he wasn’t already
>   in Gauru form. These extra dots might be enough to keep
>   the character conscious. If the Resolve + Composure roll
>   succeeds, the character remains under control, remains in
>   his current form and doesn’t go into Kuruth.

WtF p175

So does the character get 4 health dots even if they were already in Gauru form? that doesn't make sense but it seems like it might read that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No.

From the passage you have quoted: (emphasis added)

> **potentially** gaining more Health dots **if he wasn’t already in Gauru form**

Comment: so... there's no point in making a death rage roll if you're in gauru form and you go from +4 health points to 0 in a single roll. It says to make the death rage roll before going unconscious because it could keep that from happening, but I don't see how if you're in Gauru form. hence my confusion

Comment: There would be no distinct advantage, but it's still something that could happen to a character.