# Death Rage whilst recovering?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, werewolf-the-forsaken, rage

If a werewolf gets knocked out, say, over 4-5 dots in a hit. Do they immediately roll for death rage when they heal enough?

Presume [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45652/extra-health-from-death-rage-in-gauru-form) where you are already in Gauru form, which means you wouldn't have gained health, and so the knockout would have happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they were in a form with less health, shift to Gauru and gain health, and that extra health still isn't enough to have their health total fill in such that there is at least one unchecked health box, then they are unconscious because Death Rage ends at unconsciousness.

Therefore, even if the damage skips over the wounded health boxes, they are unconscious which ends Death Rage whether or not the character is suppose to enter it.